# Need to match mid part of id using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to match mid part of id 
my code is

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_OrderDate_DateTime_M"  Text="Order Date:">
</asp:Label>
```

I need to match _DateTime from ID how can I do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) to select based on a substring of an attribute:

```
$("[id*='_DateTime']")
```

It's of course worth noting that what you're showing is a server-side ASP.NET control, *not* an HTML element.  You'll want to double-check the actual HTML that you're trying to operate on with JavaScript to make sure it's what you expect it to be.

Comment: Thanks David ,your solution completely works for me thanks a lot dear